# How to set default image text and title in img tag in html when image is not loaded

Tags: html

how to set default img when there is no no image load

```html
<img src="imggirl.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display alternative text then you can do something like this.

```
<img src="imggirl.jpg" alt="girl image">
```

If you want to replace the image with default image then you can do something like this.

```js
function imageExists(image_url){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD', image_url, false);
    http.send();

    return http.status != 404;
}

const imageElement = document.getElementById('image');

if (imageExists('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png')) {
  imageElement.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png';
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png" id="image">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try like this

```html
<img src="imggirl.jpg" alt="girl_image" title="Image">
```

Comment: always use alt and title tag with img

Answer (score 0):

You can use "alt" attribute which is short for alternative text to state an alternate text for the Image
ex: